# How to set the storageservice value 'store_id' in an variable in Angular 6 in Ionic4

Tags: angular, ionic4

I am trying to get the store_id from the storageservice in Ionic4(angular 6). I got the store_id by doing

```js
let id =  this.storageService.get('store_id');
id.then(data => {
    this.store.push(data) 
});
```

i pushed it into array . Now i am unable to retrieve that store id . I am doing  `var store_id = this.store[0]` but it is showing undefined .

My StorageService code is like this

```js
async set(key: string, value: any): Promise<any> {
    try {
        const result = await this.storage.set(key, value);
        console.log('set string in storage: ' + result);
            return true;
        } catch (reason) {
            console.log(reason);
            return false;
        }
}
```

To get a key/value pair

```js
async get(key: string): Promise<any> {
    try {
            const result = await this.storage.get(key);
            console.log('storageGET: ' + key + ': ' + result);
            if (result != null) {
                return result;
            }
            return null;
        } catch (reason) {
            console.log(reason);
            return null;
        }
}
```

Set a key/value object

```js
async setObject(key: string, object: Object) {
    try {
        const result = await this.storage.set(key, JSON.stringify(object));
            console.log('set Object in storage: ' + result);
            return true;
        } catch (reason) {
            console.log(reason);
            return false;
        }
}
```

Get a key/value object

```js
async getObject(key: string): Promise<any> {
    try {
            const result = await this.storage.get(key);
            if (result != null) {
            return JSON.parse(result);
        }
            return null;
        } catch (reason) {
            console.log(reason);
            return null;
        }
}
```

Remove a single key value:

```js
remove(key: string) {
    this.storage.remove(key);
}
```

Delete all data from your application:

```js
clear() {
      this.storage.clear();
}
```

i created this through ionic create service StorageService after installing ionic storage and cordova storage 
Any help please .. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please add your `storageService` code?

Comment: @KishanBharda editing the question please wait

Answer (score 0):

You can solve by below code :

```js
async yourMethodName() {
    let data =  await this.storageService.get('store_id');
        this.store.push(data);
}
```

Comment: Gettiing the same undefined .. please wait sending you a screenshot

Comment: Are you accessing `var store_id = this.store[0]` before calling `this.storageService.get('store_id')` ?

Comment: Nope .. i am calling it after geting the store_id from StorageService